# Ubuntu 16.04 suddenly stopped connecting to wi fi connections available

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless

I was using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my dell inspiron 1564 quite happily until one day apparently for no reason it stopped connecting to my wi fi connection that it used to connect. wireless network sign on top left desktop screen is empty without any signal bars. I ran the rfkill list all & dmesg | grep b43 commands and terminal response is as under:

```
hammad@hammad-Inspiron-1564:~$ rfkill list all
hammad@hammad-Inspiron-1564:~$ dmesg | grep b43

[   15.754337] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4312 WLAN found (core revision 15)
[   15.798251] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 6, Type 5 (LP), Revision 1
[   15.798337] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2062, Revision 2, Version 0
[   16.043988] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode15.fw failed with error -2
[   16.044025] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode15.fw failed with error -2
[   16.054845] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode15.fw failed with error -2
[   16.054874] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode15.fw failed with error -2
[   16.054879] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode15.fw" not found
[   16.054886] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode15.fw" not found
```

[   16.054890] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.

I can guess that wireless driver for my wireless card is not being detected by Ubuntu anymore. Please give me any suggestions to find the solution?

Thanking you all in advance!!!!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't upload pictures of text in the question. Copy the text from the terminal by highlighting and pressing Ctrl+Shift+V and [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/964353/edit) and paste the text.  Then format the text by highlighting the text in the edit box and click the `{ }` icon above the text edit box.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep b43` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @user68186 Thank you very much for your advice. I will do as you say from now onwards in my posts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think it might be . Probably your kernel might not support the driver and has failed to detect it. You can go to your advanced ubuntu boot option while restarting and boot with a different kernel version. I had a problem with my wireless driver not detecting and I realised that my ubuntu was booting from kernel version 4.14 generic, so I booted from 4.10 generic it worked like a charm.

Comment: I booted with Linux 4.8.0-46-generic kernel instead of default Linux 4.10.0-35-generic but problem remains.